# Notifying view-model on window close

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Perhaps someone could comment on this. I have a loosely coupled view and view-model. My view-model needs to do some cleanup when the view closes. So I was wondering what would the the best way to notify view-model that its view is about to close?

Comment: either put an `EventToCommand` on `Window.Close` or just handle the `Window.Close` event in code behind and invoke the ViewModel code from there.

Comment: I use an attached behaviour because it's MVVM friendly and keeps the VM clean; but I recognize that not everybody admires attached behaviours or want to take the trouble to implement them.

Answer (score 1):

When I ran into this situation I added some `x:Code` to the XAML. It was the cleanest I could come up with.

```
<x:Code>
    <![CDATA[
    // Indirectly attach ExitCommand to the Window's close button
    private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = this.DataContext as MyViewModel;
        if(vm != null)
            vm.ExitCommand.Execute(this);
    }
    ]]>
</x:Code>
```

Make sure to include `Closed="Window_Closed"` in your `<Window>`.